# Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL SSL/TLS with Power BI desktop

Tags: postgresql, powerbi, ssl-certificate, google-cloud-sql

Is there a way to import Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL SSL/TLS certificate into Windows Trusted Root Certificate Authorities. Cloud SQL client certificate creation process provide following 3 files.

1. client-key.pem
2. client-cert.pem
3. server-ca.pem

I tried to import server-ca.pem into Windows Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and tried connection with Power BI desktop. But following error occurs.

```
The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure
```

In AWS RDS we can simply import [PKCS7 certificate bundle](https://truststore.pki.rds.amazonaws.com/global/global-bundle.p7b) into Windows Trusted Root Certificate Authorities and Power BI connects without any issue.

Connect Power BI desktop with Google Cloud SQL PostgreSQL database with provided client certificates.
Expected to connect Power BI with Google Cloud PostgreSQL with enabled SSL/TLS encryption.
Result was The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure

Comment: Have you tried disabling encryption?

To disable encryption:

1. File --> Options and settings --> Data source settings
2. Click "Edit Permissions..."
3. Uncheck "Encrypt connections"
4. Click OK

Comment: Yes. Disabling the encryption work. But in here I want to connect with SSL/TLS enabled. Because from Google Cloud SQL side it has been enforced with the SSL/TLS encryption